# What's the maximum number of Quarries/Farm/Woodcutters can you build?

Tags: shadow-kings

I'm currently Level 9 and i have 6 of each but i can build 10 farms total (6 being the maximun i can build of woodcutters and quaries). my experience in Clash of Clans is that i may be able to build more when i unlock more buildings (Shadow Kings your Level controls what you can build)

So i am wondering, what is the maximum number of Quarries/Farm/Woodcutters can i build? if i can build more at higher levels i wouldn't mind knowing at what levels these are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i have not unlocked any more Quarries/Farm/Woodcutters **In my Main City** at level 40. however you can build more if you get an Outpost.

When selecting an Outpost to take there are 2 resources, Food and Wood or Stone, the number bellow them is how many maximum you can build to get each resource. the Maximum i have seen is 14 for a single resource and one of the 3 resources will be dominate having the most number, the other resource will have (from what i have seen) at most 4